# "A quote, quoted by someone that I happen to read on the internet"

Tags: sentence-construction

> “I am alone, and this loneliness is killing me”, is a quote, quoted by someone that I happen to read on the internet

Is the sentence after the quote correct?

What I’m trying to say is that I saw this quote on the internet. The quote is not the problem, but is the sentence I wrote after the quote correct?
I hope that when people read this they can understand what I am trying to say, especially if written in a blog or journal.

If the sentence is wrong, how would you put it?

Comment: Yes, syntactically your cited text is "correct". But I'd say using "quote" as a verb immediately after using it as a noun is stylistically weak. It's also poor *semantically*, because most likely this "someone you read on the internet" was *the actual person who originally said/wrote* the cited "quote". But "to quote" [some text] doesn't mean to *produce* it (as an original utterance) - it means ***to cite something someone else said or wrote***. Just get rid of the second instance of "quote" - *...this loneliness is killing me” is a quote **from** someone that I happen to read...*

Comment: ...I don't know if you were concerned about the "validity" of the cited "quote" itself, but I'd say it's a bit of a stretch from *I am alone* to ***this** loneliness...* On purely stylistic grounds, I think I'd prefer *...and **my** loneliness is killing me* to strengthen the link between the two clauses.

Comment: People used to object to the use of "quote" as a noun and say you should use "quotation" instead; possibly in school assignments you should follow this rule, although in most contexts it is very common to say "a quote".

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically it is almost completely fine, but I would use 'happened', since this occurred in the past and does not occur at this very moment:

> "A quote, quoted by someone that I happen*ed* to read on the internet"

In addition, as FumbleFingers mentions in a comment, the double use of quote is not very appealing. You can use 'cite' as an alternative for the verb 'quote', or 'citation' for the noun 'quote'.

Nevertheless, I'd leave out the "*quoted by someone*", because the fact that an anonymous user also happened to cite this quotation - and that this person was thus not the original source - is of no consequence to either the interpretation of the quote nor the person you're citing it to:

> x *is a quotation I found/read on the internet.*

Moreover, when you say "*I found a quote*", it implies that it was presented to you in that form — that is, as a quote.
Otherwise you could say "*I'm quoting something (a sentence, a paragraph, &c.) I found on the internet*".